# How do I convert a row of numbers to a row of letters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to build my first Python script. I want to convert a row of numbers to a row of letters.

```
Example: From 0123456789 to ACGDBFVKIP
```

I've written a very basic code that only allows the conversion of a single number but not for a row of numbers. I'm pretty sure there's something wrong at the loop portion of the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
print('Enter number here: ')
integer = input()
while not(integer.isdigit()):
    print('only numbers!')
    print('Enter number here: ')
    integer = input()


NumToLetter = {'0': 'A', '1': 'C', '2': 'G', '3': 'D', '4': 'B', '5': 'F', '6': 'V', '7': 'K', '8': 
'I', '9': 'P'}


letter = ''
integer_length = len(integer)


if integer_length > 0:
   letter = NumToLetter[integer]

print(letter)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a loop to translate all numbers to letters. After you get the input, you can do something like this:

```
result = ''
for num in integer:
    result += NumToLetter[num]

print(result)
```

But there is an easier way, [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
result = integer.translate(str.maketrans('0123456789','ACGDBFVKIP'))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `integer` is the number, try like this:

```
integer = str(integer)
for num,let in NumToLetter.items():
    integer = integer.replace(num,let)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `NumToLetter` maps a single digit to a letter, and input is a string of digits. Instead of this you can loop over every number in your input, map it to a letter, and then add it to the result. For example:

```
print('Enter number here: ')
number_input = input()
while not number_input.isdigit():
    print('only numbers!')
    print('Enter number here: ')
    number_input = input()


NumToLetter = {'0': 'A', '1': 'C', '2': 'G', '3': 'D', '4': 'B', '5': 'F', '6': 'V', '7': 'K', '8': 
'I', '9': 'P'}


number_length = len(number_input)
if number_length > 0:
    letters = ""
    for number in number_input:
        letters += NumToLetter[number]

    print(letters)
```

Input: `123`

Output: `CGD`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [map](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/) function:

```
numbers = '0123456789'
NumToLetter = {'0': 'A', '1': 'C', '2': 'G', '3': 'D', '4': 'B', '5': 'F', '6': 'V', '7': 'K', '8':
'I', '9': 'P'}
letters = "".join(map(lambda x: NumToLetter[x], list(numbers)))
print(letters) # ACGDBFVKIP
```

Basically, `map` apply the lambda function to `list(numbers)` and `list(numbers)` is:

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Comment: This will work in more efficient way if lambda is replaced by `NumToLetter.__getitem__` as the method over which list is to be iterated.

Comment: Nice point @JenilDave but, I used this approach because I think is easier to understand.